# Can I install Google Chrome plugins or themes in the Steam-based browser?

Tags: steam

Is it possible to install Google Chrome plugins or themes in the Steam-based integrated browser? Or, is there any way to get themes or extensions for the Steam webkit browser?

For example, a dark theme and Lastpass would be wonderful!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't get Chrome plugins for the steam overlay browser because that browser isn't chrome.  At this time, I don't believe Valve has mentioned any plans to support extensions or plugins in the overlay browser.

Comment: Extensions are more of a browser feature than a part of WebKit. Even importing it from Chrome wouldn't guarantee compatibility.